# how to create users and log in/out sessions using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am new to rails and I am trying to build a simple web site where it requires creating users that are able to log in and out
but when creating the user I get
**ArgumentError in UsersController#create
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)**
and this happens also when I try to log in where I get
**ArgumentError in SessionsController#create
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)**

### any thoughts on how to fix this ?

the model for the user is as follows

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :password

#validation for password on creation.
validates :password, :presence => true,
                  :confirmation => true,
                  :length => {:within => 6..40},
                  :on => :create

#validation for password on update, forget password option
validates :password, :confirmation => true,
                  :length => {:within => 6..40},
                  :on => :update

validates :user_name, presence: true,
                    uniqueness: true

validates :status, presence: true

before_save :encrypt_password

def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
end

def self.authenticate(user_name, password)
    user = find_by_user_name(user_name)   
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      #authenticate
      user
    else
      # la2 :(
        nil
    end
end

end
```

and the user controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


def new
  @user = User.new
  end

  def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
  end


  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:user_name, :status, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

and regarding the sessions it has no model
where the session controller is as follows :

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
  user = User.authenticate(params[:user_name], params[:password])
  if user
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    render "new"
  end
end

def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
end

end
```

Comment: check your callback "before_save",  it seems that password_salt is blank

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea to roll your own security.

I would highly recommend checking out [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)